# Java ADF JDeveloper: Set View Object's current row to null

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have this functionality where the pages doesn't have to show a current row of a view object. It always sets to the first row.

Things I've tried so far:

```
VO.executeQuery();
VO.setCurrentRow(null);
```

None of these are working, and I can't find useful documentation. Please consider I just started a month ago with this technology.

Comment: You need to be clearer about exactly what the problem is. What exactly are you wanting to do? What do you expect the vo to do?

Comment: @Joe I had this particular view where I needed to set the current row of a View Object to null. I figured it out it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear.
However, if you want not to display any rows of the VO, then you can try this:

```
VO.setMaxFetchSize(0);
VO.executeQuery();
```

The setMaxFetchSize(0) method sets the maximum rows to be picked up as 0,i.e., when the VO is executed, no rows will be fetched.

Do let us know, if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. But I found out View Objects need to have current row != null when VO.length > 0